# watchdog in vc++ application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, watchdog

I have written a simple vc++ background application. What am trying is like a watchdog service that could monitor if the application is running or not. If the application crashed then the service should start the application

For creating a setup through windows installer am using only the app.exe and app.dll.
Is that possible to create this watchdog - service in the exe itself ?

Unfortunately I have no idea of how to write such a program, does anyone have some example code that would demonstrate this technique please?

if so then how to make the default exe and watchdog exe as a single application to install ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687416(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your best route would be to create a separate service to act as the watchdog. Technically, it's possible to have the service and the "real application" in the same executable. You can differentiate between the two depending on how the exe has been started, but it will make maintenance quite difficult.

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16488/A-Windows-Service-Application) might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. if i create a separate service to act as the watchdog, then it seems i have to insall both application setup and watchdog setup right ?

Comment: You can have one setup install both service and the application. What program will you be using to create the installer?

Comment: visual studio 2008 setup and deployment.

Comment: can u please explain how to handle both in a single installer

Answer (score 1):

Here - http://yadi.sk/d/EtzBRSMi3FqVH - is my implementation of WatchDog app, working in systray. Do not mind that it's written with Qt - the main functionality is with WinAPI.
This app is watching in processes list for several processes and restarts them if can't find. The second feature is that it monitors all windows in system for suspicious window title (for ex. "'My Great App' causes a system error and will be closed. Send message to developers ?") and, if find, restarts them too

P.S. I didn't i18n it, but I think there will no troubles )

**Update:** (according to @CodyGray comment)

Here's pastebin's links: [WatchDog.cpp](http://pastebin.com/YmEygbnQ) and [WatchDog.h](http://pastebin.com/Cx0hckc4)

Comment: In general, posting example code as part of your answer is way better than posting links to random, untrustworthy ZIP files.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought about it, but there's about 120 realy useful lines: looking for processes with `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot/Process32First/Process32Next`, looking for windows with `EnumWindows`, comparing window titles with regex, etc. Nevertheless, thank you for critics. I'll dub it at pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Such a watchdog can be set up to, for example, write to a file every minute (or whatever). If the file hasn't been updated in two or more minutes then there is most likely a deadlock in the application and it has to be restarted.

Comment: yes my application writes a file whenever there is an activity. But if the app crashes with exceptional error, then how to do