# Install Windows Service and Console Application using a single setup and deployment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-services, watchdog

I have created a console application that works as background app in *C++*. I am trying to run this application through windows service to start automatically if the app crashed.

What I can't do is to create a windows service which can trigger the `xxx.exe`.

How can I make this windows service AND background application as a single setup file for installation ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [watchdog in vc++ application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383883/watchdog-in-vc-application)